# Intermediatevalue-type Proposition for measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $X$ be real valued random variables on a measure space with measure $\mu$ and let $X_n\rightarrow X$ $\mu$-almost surely. I was wondering if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\mu(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$$

Here is my proof for this little proposition and I am unsure if it is correct:

Let $A_n:=\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}$ then because the convergence is almost surely we have
$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\searrow N$ for some $\mu$-nullset $N$. By uppercontinuity of the measure it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(N)=0$. In other words
$$\forall\varepsilon' >0\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,\forall n\ge N\colon |\mu(A_n)-\mu(N)|<\varepsilon'\\
\Leftrightarrow |\mu(A_n)|<\varepsilon'$$

and in particular for $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Sequence of sets $(A_n)$ isn't decreasing, so argument with continuity of $\mu$ fails at this point. I'd rather consider sets $A_m = \bigcup_{n \ge m} \{ |X_n - X| > \varepsilon \}$. Now, we want to show $ \mu(\bigcap_m A_m) = 0 $ (which can be done due to convergence almost surely), and now similarly as you (now it is decreasing sequence of sets), we get for some $m > N$: $\mu(A_m) <\varepsilon '$ and in particular taking $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon$ we get for $n > m$: $\mu (\{|X_n - X | > \varepsilon\} \le  \mu(A_m) < \varepsilon$

Comment: By the way, the property that $\mu(|X_n - X|) \to 0$ (which is equivalent to the property you describe) is called convergence in measure.